# Is it a code smell to put selection strategy concerns in an enum class?

Tags: code-smell, test-automation, groovy

Right now, I have this enum, called `MemberCategory`, defined to be:

```
public enum MemberCategory {
    MEMBERSHIP("Membership"),
    GOLD_MEMBERSHIP("Gold"),
    SILVER_MEMBERSHIP("Silver"),
    STANDARD_MEMBERSHIP("Standard"),
    PEDIATRIC("Child")

    public final String textValue;

    public MemberCategory(String textValue) {
        this.textValue = textValue;
    }

    public static MemberCategory valueOfText(String textValue) {
        for (MemberCategory category : values()) {
            if (category.textValue.equals(textValue))
                return category;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

which, right now, contains `textValue` field, whose use cases are as follows:

- by model (collection) builders: mapping a column value to the correct model/member category
- by test cases: writing the autocomplete search term into the autocomplete input

Mapping text value to member category, is handled by `valueOfText` static method. This is the case for many of the enums used in my code base.

I have this handle-autocomplete util method which I am refactoring to bring in selection strategies.

Is it code smell to introduce, directly into the `MemberCategory` class itself, the selection strategy for each member category, considering that the autocomplete widget for a member category works the same for any page it's on?

Comment: By "selection strategies", you mean what precisely? The strategy how your "autocomplete feature" will select a value from a partial input? Please clarify.

Comment: Ya, I have a util method that handles autocomplete widget on the page, and the selection strategy refers to....how we are to handle selection of the dropdown option, based on the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong in placing more small, self-contained member functions for `MemberCategory`s and `String`s inside the `MemberCategory` class (yes, in Java, an `enum` is nothing but a special class). If your selection strategy method fits to that description, go ahead.

What you should care for is how complex the new method becomes, if it is easily testable and if it may require additional dependencies. @mtj gave a nice example: internationalization may require a dependency to something like a `translator` class, but I can imagine other unpleasant dependencies like some event mechanics or UI dependencies.

When this happens (maybe later, during constant evolvement of the program), then it is a good idea to refactor the "selection strategy" out of the enum class to avoid this dependency. But don't overthink this for now, start with a simple design which suits your current needs, and refactor when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your text value is a technical value, that can never change, there is no problem with this pattern.

However, if you are talking about autocompleting input, this seems to be a text used in a user interface, which may lead to some future problems:

- you cannot internationalize your software
- you cannot introduce aliases (e.g. due to renaming the products for new users at a certain time)

Therefore, better rethink this approach.

Comment: Internationalization and aliases are NOT concerns for me or the company I work for, also this is piece of web automation testing code, nothing more. 

Also, anything I come up with other than this, will either be too error-prone (think silent errors that we have no idea are happening at test runtime), or too complicated.

Comment: In this case, the future problem points are void, and I see no issues with your approach.